# Row locking to update

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have innodb table read by lot of different instances (cloud)

Daemon in each instance takes 100 rows to "do things" of this table, but I don't want 2 (or more) instances to take the same things.

So I have a "status" column ("todo", "doing", "done").

INSTANCE 1: It takes 100 rows where status = "todo" ... Then I need to UPDATE these rows asap to status "doing", so INSTANCE 2,3,..x can't take the same rows.

How can i do it ?

Please, I would like a solution without LOCKING WHOLE table, but locking just the rows (that's because I use innodb) ... I have read a lot about that (LOCK SHARE MODE, FOR UPDATE, COMMITs ... ) but I do not get the right way ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES functions to do this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: That would freeze out the other daemon. Maybe the DB stuff takes a very short period compared to the processing, but it locks everyone for some period of time. For this, row-level locking is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes Marc B ... I'm looking that ... row locking, but I do not know how to do it ... I have read tons of documentation, but I don't find examples , and I do not know how to do it exactly :(

Answer (score 0):

use a transaction and then `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` when you read the records.
This way the records you read are locked. When you get all the data update the records to "doing" and `COMMIT` the transaction.
Maybe what you were missing is the use of a transaction, or the correct order of commands. Here is a basic example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE STATUS = 'todo' FOR UPDATE;

// Loop over results in code, save necessary data to array/list..

UPDATE table SET STATUS ='doing' WHERE ...;
COMMIT;

// process the data...

UPDATE table SET STATUS ='done' WHERE ...;
```